# Thymeleaf th:field overwrites th:value

Tags: java, html, thymeleaf

I just figured out that the `th:field` attribute overrides the `th:value` attribute.

In my `th:each` I want to override the value that `th:field` generates for me. Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

```html
<ul id="userGroupContainer">
 <li class="clickable unselected" th:each="u, rowStat : ${userNotInGroup}" th:if="${u.id}">
      <input type="text" readonly="readonly" hidden="hidden" disabled="disabled" th:field="* {users[__${rowStat.index}__].id}" th:value="${u.id}" />
      <input type="text" readonly="readonly" hidden="hidden" disabled="disabled" th:field="* {users[__${rowStat.index}__].displayName}" th:value="${u.displayName}" />
      <input type="text" readonly="readonly" hidden="hidden" disabled="disabled" th:field="* {users[__${rowStat.index}__].username}" th:value="${u.username}" />
      <input type="text" readonly="readonly" hidden="hidden" disabled="disabled" th:field="*{users[__${rowStat.index}__].emailAddress}" th:value="${u.emailAddress}" />
        <span th:text="${u.displayName}"></span>
 </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thymeleaf `th:field` generates 3 html attributes `id`, `name` an `value`.

For your case, instead of using `th:field`, use `th:id`, `th:name` and `th:value` as shown below.

```
<input type="text" th:id="${'users'+__${rowStat.index}__+'.id'}" th:name="${'users['+__${rowStat.index}__+'].id'}" th:value="${u.id}" readonly="readonly" hidden="hidden" disabled="disabled"/>
<input type="text" th:id="${'users'+__${rowStat.index}__+'.displayName'}" th:name="${'users['+__${rowStat.index}__+'].displayName'}" th:value="${u.displayName}" readonly="readonly" hidden="hidden" disabled="disabled"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Like faizi said above you should change the `th:field` for `th:id`, `th:name` and `th:value`. I'd just like to add that the values for my `th:id` and `th:name` were just the name of my column in my entity (in my case testID). Hopefully the example below helps anyone.

```
<td><input th:value="${request.testID}" th:id="testID" th:name="testID"/></td>
```